# get time zone and compare with other time zones with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, timezone

How do you get the current time zone offset in hours with javascript, store it in a database, and compare with other time zone rows in the database to get the time zone difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to write the full code because that would take hours but here is the gist of it...

First get the offset with JS. Here is a nice sample on the MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

Then pass that to the server-side using AJAX. jQuery allows you to do this nicely..

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( 
    "ajax/store-date.php", 
    { 
        offset: currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours 
    },
    function( data ) {
        // success callback.
    });
```

On the PHP side store this in the database. There are many ways to do this.. here is a basic one..

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Offsets (offset) VALUES (" . floatval($_POST['offset']) . ")";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

To compare use SQL such as...

```
SELECT SUM(offset) FROM Offsets
WHERE id IN (1,10) /* add the 2 entry id's you want to compare */
```

As stated before, there is TONNES of extra code missing, but that is irrelevant to the scope of the question.